# Two line expressions using a single bracket

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to fit two expression inside a large bracket something like this:

[image: img]

I looked some of the examples like this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109258/two-double-line-equations-need-double-left-brackets), however, I need variables such as `x1` instead of `1`. Help appreciated.

Comment: Do you need a matrix? Use `$S=\begin{pmatrix} x_1,\ldots,x_n \\ y_1,\ldots,y_n \end{pmatrix}$`. Load `\usepakage{amsmath}` to use it. If you want romam letters, use `\mathrm{S}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! `array`s such as those in the example you link to isn't limited to single numbers, so you could just replace `1` with `x_1`. Sigur's approach is better though, I think.

Comment: Sorry, typo on `\usepackage`. I can not edit it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Sigur suggested is more than likely the answer, but here is an alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{S}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1,\dotsc,x_n \\ y_1,\dotsc,y_n \end{pmatrix}$
$\displaystyle\mathrm{S}=\binom{x_1,\dotsc,x_n}{y_1,\dotsc,y_n}$
\end{document}
```

I also suggest using the command `\dotsc` for comma separated sequences. I suggest reading one of the following answers:

1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122493/10898
2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122497/10898